# PowerBI Matrix Average instead of Subtotal and Conditional Formatting According to That Average

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, powerbi-desktop

Hello I am just new in powerBI and it is still hard to work on for me.
I have a matrix like that

```
DATE     Sales      Refund
26 Agu      45          5
    p1      10          3
    p2      15          2
    p3      20          0
27 Agu      60          1
    p1      15          1
    p2      20          0
    p3      25          0
```

In the date parts I have subtotals as it normally does. However, I want to show the average of that day there and when I get the average I will make conditional formatting according to it. If a cell is below average I will mark it with red point and in refunds I will do it for the values above the average.
Is there a way to do that. I searched for it for awhile but could not find.

The output I want is like that. (star is for red point.)

```
DATE     Sales      Refund
26 Agu      15          1.66
    p1      10*         3*
    p2      15          2*
    p3      20          0
27 Agu      20          0.33
    p1      15*         1*
    p2      20          0
    p3      25          0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can colour the background; For example, create this measure:

```
AVG = 
IF( SELECTEDVALUE(RefundTab[Sale] ) <  CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), ALL(RefundTab[Code])),0,1)
```

From menu -> Conditional formatting -> Background color:

[image]

And here:
[image]
[image]

OR

you can create measure where we return string instead of number where we put some unicode value:

```
SumSaleIf = 

var _sale = sum(RefundTab[Sale])
var _IfAVG = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), ALL(RefundTab[Code]))
var _check = if(_sale < _IfAVG, _sale & UNICHAR(128315), _sale &"")
return _check
```

[image]

Comment: What about adding the average to the top next to each date ? Is it possible. 
Thank you for your great answer it is really harder than regular development :)

Comment: create measure as MyAVG = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), ALL(RefundTab[Code])); AVG will show on each row; If you want only on "Date" level then use:

MyAVG = 
if(HASONEVALUE(RefundTab[Code]), BLANK(),
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), ALL(RefundTab[Code]))
)

Comment: I have one more need since you are expert when I compare myself I would like to ask you directly. What if I want to see the averages of the P2 Sales ? I understand the other parst but to apply it in dax I have doubts

Comment: If you want to get average only for certain CODE for all date then:
fast example
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), FILTER( ALL(RefundTab[Code]), RefundTab[Code] = "P2"    ))

If you need to take Code dynamically then:

CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RefundTab[Sale]), FILTER( ALL(RefundTab), RefundTab[Code] = SELECTEDVALUE(RefundTab[Code])   ))